# How to display data from database into textbox, and update it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I can display my data in my textbox, dropdownlist after retrieve data from sql database, but when i proceed with my update button, the information edited in the textbox or dropdownlist wouldn't update into the database. I tried to remove the code in page load, and re-key in all the data manually, it can be update. All I want is retrieve data from database and display it in the textbox, and it can be update into the database after make some changes from the textbox. Can someone help me on this? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
public partial class UpdateCustomerDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=webservice_database;Integrated Security=True");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con1.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;  
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from customer_registration where username='" + Session["username"] + "'", con1);

    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        TextBoxPassword.Text = (myReader["password"].ToString());
        TextBoxRPassword.Text = (myReader["retypepassword"].ToString());
        DropDownListGender.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["gender"].ToString());
        DropDownListMonth.Text = (myReader["birth"].ToString());
        DropDownListYear.Text = (myReader["birth"].ToString());
        TextBoxAddress.Text = (myReader["address"].ToString());
        TextBoxCity.Text = (myReader["city"].ToString());
        DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["country"].ToString());
        TextBoxPostcode.Text = (myReader["postcode"].ToString());
        TextBoxEmail.Text = (myReader["email"].ToString());
        TextBoxCarno.Text = (myReader["carno"].ToString());
    }
    con1.Close();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=webservice_database;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE customer_registration SET password = @password, retypepassword = @retypepassword, gender = @gender, birth = @birth, address = @address, city = @city, country = @country, postcode = @postcode, email = @email, carno = @carno where username='" + Session["username"] + "'", con);
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@retypepassword", TextBoxRPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownListGender.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth", DropDownListDay.Text + DropDownListMonth.Text + DropDownListYear.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBoxAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBoxCity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownListCountry.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", TextBoxPostcode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carno", TextBoxCarno.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Redirect("UpdateSuccess.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your all statements in `!IsPostBack` condition on page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      // all statements
   }
}
```

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `.IsPostBack` as suggested by @Kundan Singh Chouhan. Just to add to it, move your code into a separate method from Page_Load

```
private void PopulateFields()
{
  using(SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=webservice_database;Integrated Security=True"))
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con1.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;  
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from customer_registration where username='" + Session["username"] + "'", con1);

    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        TextBoxPassword.Text = (myReader["password"].ToString());
        TextBoxRPassword.Text = (myReader["retypepassword"].ToString());
        DropDownListGender.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["gender"].ToString());
        DropDownListMonth.Text = (myReader["birth"].ToString());
        DropDownListYear.Text = (myReader["birth"].ToString());
        TextBoxAddress.Text = (myReader["address"].ToString());
        TextBoxCity.Text = (myReader["city"].ToString());
        DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["country"].ToString());
        TextBoxPostcode.Text = (myReader["postcode"].ToString());
        TextBoxEmail.Text = (myReader["email"].ToString());
        TextBoxCarno.Text = (myReader["carno"].ToString());
    }
    con1.Close();
  }//end using
}
```

Then call it in your Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       PopulateFields();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you clicked on the Save button, the Page_Load was called again and it refilled your controls with values from the database. This overwrites your new entry...

Comment: Previously I was confusing about when to use IsPostBack, now I know when IsPostBack == false, it load the page_load for the first time, when IsPostBack == true, it make some changes after button are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        DropDownTitle();
    }


protected void DropDownTitle()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuzineConnection"].ConnectionString;

        string selectSQL = "select DISTINCT ForumTitlesID,ForumTitles from ForumTtitle";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {

            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = "Select";
            newItem.Value = "0";
            ForumTitleList.Items.Add(newItem);
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListItem newItem1 = new ListItem();
                newItem1.Text = reader["ForumTitles"].ToString();
                newItem1.Value = reader["ForumTitlesID"].ToString();
                ForumTitleList.Items.Add(newItem1);



            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Populate the text box values in the Page Init event as opposed to using the Postback.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownTitle();
}
```