# How can show date type data from mysql server in textbox and datagrid in c#.net

Tags: c#, mysql, datetimepicker

I want to make a database to store date type data in a colum and i store date by datetimepicker now i try to retrive data from database and show in the textbox and datagrid view in c#.net

Comment: what you tried for it.show your code.

Comment: Which database? how do you store and read data, what do you use?

Comment: Refer this link there is example.How to retrieve data from database and display in textbox and in another controls.[Display Date in textbox](http://forums.asp.net/t/1918270.aspx?Display+Data+in+Textbox+Next+Previous+First+Last+form+database+in+asp+net+and+c+) and [StackOverflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113025/how-to-display-data-from-database-into-textbox-and-update-it)