# Update DB with updated Textbox Information in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Trying to update the first name of the student there is a textbox "FirstNameTextbox" information was loaded to it from the DB, when I change the information in the textbox and try to write the changes it read only the original data.So if it loaded "Craig" as the first name from the DB, i would edit and put "Chris" in the textbox, what happens is that Craig is written to the DB and not "Chris"

```
int stuID = getSqlStuID(IDNUMLabel.Text);
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
string sqlUpdateStudent = "Update tblStudent set fname = @fname where stuID = @stuID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdateStudent, conn);

conn.Open();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuID", stuID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", FirstNameTextbox.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

ErrorMessage.Text = "Success";


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        IDNUMLabel.Text = Session["User"].ToString();
        getStuData(Session["User"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Login/Login.aspx");
    }
}

private void getStuData(string id)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    string sql = "Select fname, sname From tblStudent Where idnumber = '" + id + "' ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader selectedRecord = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        while (selectedRecord.Read())
        {
            FirstNameTextbox.Text = selectedRecord["fname"].ToString();
            LastNameTextbox.Text = selectedRecord["sname"].ToString();
        }

        selectedRecord.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {

        //id = 0;
        //string msg = "Error reading Student ID";
        //msg += ex.Message;
        //throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: set a breakpoint at cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", FirstNameTextbox.Text);. What is the value of stuID? Is there such an entry in your db? Check the value of @fname as well.

Comment: Looks like clasic 'load the info in all page loads' issue. Please, edit your question and add the loading into the control code, and explain in what event and conditions is executed

Comment: Take a look, added it not too long ago

Comment: @hellogoodnight, stuID would be the primary key in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At what point do you make the actual update? After a button was pressed, after the value was entered on the textbox...? You're missing the method in which the code that handles the update is placed...
Maybe this could help: [How to display data from database into textbox, and update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113025/how-to-display-data-from-database-into-textbox-and-update-it)

Comment: Thanks Danilo, this is exactly the type of solution i was looking for. #Respect